# texmf-local on Dropbox?

Tags: texmf

how local does texmf-local have to be?

I have about 6 different computers, osx and linux, different versions, some on virtual machines.  can I create one `~/Dropbox/texmf-local/` folder, and *ln -s* it to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` (replacing the stub tree) on each of my 6 machines?  this way, I would not need to customize individual machines.  I just customize "me" once, and my modifications would propagate to any of my computers immediatley.  possible?

I am positive this works with the latex input style files.  they are just ASCII files that are the same across architectures.

I am not sure that it works with fonts.  the resulting font files may not be platform-agnostic...or are they?

after I have hooked in such a universally shared texmf-local, do I need to run a `texhash` on each machine, or only once on one machine?  if `texhash` writes its `ls-lR.gz` into the top directory, doing it once may well be all that is needed.  what about the fonts---`mktexlsr` and `updmap` `-sys` ?

tex wizard help appreciated.

Comment: It works with fonts as well. What you have to do on the various machine is to add the dropbox folder to the local `TEXMF` system variable or link the local texmf-local folder to it.

Comment: The only problem that I can think of is having to build the TeX file database whenever you add files to or remove files from the local tree.

Comment: To avoid rebuiding the Tex file database, share the personnal texmf tree.

Comment: thank you.  one warning to others going this route: if you use Dropbox, there is a sync period.  you cannot try it immediately elsewhere.  make sure to let it complete.  otherwise, the latex errors can be baffling.  trust me on this---I tried it out.

Comment: I did  the same thing using github!